# Reformat a regex as a C# verbatim string literal

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regex pattern and would like to use the @ symbol in front of the string so that you don't need to escape the regex escape characters. When I try that I keep getting a compilation error saying "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used in a statement". I am sure I need to remove the escape characters that I have in my string before I can use @. However I am not able to get it to work. Can someone help get the below string pattern modified to use @ at the start.

```
^\\s*\\{(\\s*,?\\s*\\\"([^\"]*)\\\"\\s*:\\s*\\\"([^\"]*)\\\")*\\}\\s*$
```

Comment: mybe it is possible to do that: different environments hve different rules start/end markers.  where do you want to use the regex.

Comment: visual studio using c#

Comment: You need to show sample of what you tried so someone can help you with resolving error you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a regex that was written in a language like C or Java that doesn't have regex literals or a friendly quoting mechanism (like Python's raw strings), and you want to include it in a C# program, using a verbatim string literal to get rid of the excess backslashes.  I'm sure you're aware that C# still supports the old-style quotes, so you can use the regex as it is:

```
"^\\s*\\{(\\s*,?\\s*\\\"([^\"]*)\\\"\\s*:\\s*\\\"([^\"]*)\\\")*\\}\\s*$"
```

But here it is as a verbatim string:

```
@"^\s*\{(\s*,?\s*\""([^""]*)\""\s*:\s*\""([^""]*)\"")*\}\s*$"
```

This was generated by RegexBuddy, by the way.  I pasted in the first string (with the quotes), told it it came from a Java program, and it got rid of the enclosing quotes and extra backslashes.  Then I told it I was copying it to a C# program, so it added the new quotes (`@"..."`) and doubled up quotes inside the regex.  And that's the least of what RB can do--highly recommended!

What it didn't do is get rid of the extra backslash before the internal quotes.  That is, it faithfully converted `\\\"` to `\""`.  That's not incorrect, but the quote character has no special meaning inside a regex, so the backslash isn't needed.  Here's how I would write it:

```
@"^\s*\{(\s*,?\s*""([^""]*)""\s*:\s*""([^""]*)"")*\}\s*$"
```